# Looping through results using while loops just once

Tags: php, mysql

Any idea why this only loops through once? I am trying to have nested panels for each result from the DB. I know there are probably a lot of bad practices here, but I just need it to work for a class. This is never going into production.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo sizeof($row);

    $resId=$row[reservationId];
    $counter++;

    try {
        $startDate = new DateTime($row[startDate]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit(1);
    }
    try {
        $endDate = new DateTime($row[endDate]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit(1);
    }
    echo "
    <div class=\"panel-group\" id=\"accordion".$counter."\">
    <div class=\"panel panel-default\">
    <div class=\"panel-heading\">
    <h4 class=\"panel-title\"><a class=\"panel-toggle\" data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-parent=\"#accordion".$counter."\" href=\"#collapseInner".$counter."\"><label> ".$row[title]." </label> <label class=\"pull-right\">".$startDate->format('m-d-Y')."</label></a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id=\"collapseInner".$counter."\" class=\"panel-body collapse\">
        <div class=\"panel-inner\">
    <div class=\"col-lg-8\">
    <p><label>Lodging Reservation #:01-".$row[reservationId]."</label></p>
    <p><label>Check In: ".$startDate->format('m-d-Y')."</label></p>
    <p><label>Check Out: ".$endDate->format('m-d-Y')."</label></p>
    </div>
    <div class=\"col-lg-4\">
    <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-lg\" data-toggle=\"modal\"
        data-target=\"#myModal".$counter."\">
    Edit Reservation</button>
     <!-- Modal -->
        <div class=\"modal fade\" id=\"myModal".$counter."\" tabindex=\"-1\"
        role=\"dialog\" aria-labelledby=\"myModalLabel\" aria-hidden=\"true\">
    <div class=\"modal-dialog\">
        <div class=\"modal-content\">
    <div class=\"modal-header\">
        <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" aria
        hidden=\"true\">&times; </button>
        <h4 class=\"modal-title\" id=\"myModalLabel\">Edit Reservation</h4>
        </div>
    <div class=\"modal-body\">
    <form method=\"post\" action=\"../controller/EditLodgingReservation.php?
        rId=".$resId."&counter=".$counter."\">
    <label>Select Dates:</label>
    <div class=\"input-group\">
    <div class=\"input-group-addon\">
    <i class=\"fa fa-calendar\"></i>
    </div>
    <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control pull-right\" 
        id=\"reservation".$counter."\" name=\"reservation".$counter."\">
    </div><!-- /.input group -->
    <label>Select Lodging</label>
    <select multiple=\"\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"lodgingList".$counter."\" 
        name=\"lodgingList".$counter."\">
    ";

    $result = getlodging();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value=".$row[lodgingId].">".$row[title]." -- $".$row[ratePerDay]." 
          /night</option>";
    }
    echo"
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class=\"modal-footer\">
    <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" data-
        dismiss=\"modal\">Close</button>
    <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">Save changes</button></a>
    </div>
     </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
     <p></p>
     <form method=\"post\" action=\"../controller/DeleteLodgingReservation.php?
     rId=".$resId."&pId=".$personId."\">
     <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-danger btn-lg\">Delete Reservation</button>
     </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>";    
}
?>
```

Comment: For starters, why are you calling `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {` twice?

Comment: Quoting `$row` keys would be nice as well ;)

Comment: @John you were on the right track. They are both there because I am populating a select box with info from the DB on the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting your first $row variable with your second while loop.

Comment: Wow thank you. I can't believe I missed that. I guess my brain has had it.